# list multiple file types in bash for loop

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I wrote a script that converts images in a folder.  The script uses a for loop:

```
i="1"
for file in *.jpg; do
     outputFile=$(echo "image"$(echo $i))
     convert "$file" -resize 50x50 $outputFile
     i=$[i+1]
done
```

What I want to do is allow the script to run on multiple file type extensions. Now I've tried doing:

```
for file in *.jpg *.JPG *.jpeg; do
....
done
```

The problem I have with this is that if you are in a folder with all *.JPG and no *.jpg, the script still bumps i+1 even though there was no images, because it runs the for loop anyways, upon not finding any *.jpg it goes onto *.JPG.

How can I target multiple file extensions without it running itself per type? Example, is their syntax something like this:

```
for file in [*.jpg | *.JPG]; do
...
```

?
That way my output folder always contains images labeled like this:
image1.jpg
image2.jpg
image3.jpg
etc..

Instead of ending up with a folder missing image1.jpg because it had no *.jpg to run on first.

Comment: ...but what about to use an `if [ -e "$file" ]`...`fi` and execute conversion and increment only when the file exists? (You can use other tests to check for link etc etc). It should protect even in case you have a directory named Jpg.

Answer (score 8):

#### The Solution

Use nullglob.  Put the following line before the `for` loop:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

`nullglob` means that if there is no such file, the glob is removed from the list.  Observe without nullglob:

```
$ echo  *.jpg *.JPG *.jpeg
test.jpg *.JPG *.jpeg
```

Now, with nullglob:

```
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ echo  *.jpg *.JPG *.jpeg
test.jpg
```

#### Revised Script

The complete script could be:

```
i=1
shopt -s nullglob
for file in *.jpg *.JPG *.jpeg; do
     convert "$file" -resize 50x50 "image$i.jpg"
     i=$((i+1))
done
```

Three notes:

1. In the definition of `outputFile`, all those `echo` statements were unnecessary.
2. Following convention, I added an extension, `.jpg`, to your output file name.  If you really don't want the extension, just remove it.
3. I replace `$[...]` with its more standard form: `$((...))`.

Comment: A more reliable way to find *all* JPEGs in the current directory: `file * | grep 'JPEG image data' | cut -d: -f1`

Comment: @Dummy00001:  Of course that fails if you have file(s) whose name(s) contain “JPEG image data” or ‘**`:`**’.

Answer (score 5):

1. Since you want to look for
   multiple *distinct* (case insensitive) extensions,
   the `shopt -s nullglob` answer is a very good one to use.
2. If you were simply looking for `*.jpg`, `*.JPG`,
   and the other six various combinations of upper case and lower case,
   the easiest thing to do would be

   ```
    for file in *.[Jj][Pp][Gg]
   ```

   which looks for files whose names are

   - (something), followed by
   - `.` (a period), followed by
   - `J` or `j`, followed by
   - `P` or `p`, followed by
   - `G` or `g`

   in other words,

   - (something), followed by
   - `.` (a period), followed by
   - "jpg", in some combination of upper case and lower case
3. So one way to solve your problem is

   ```
    shopt -s nullglob
    for file in *.[Jj][Pp][Gg] *.[Jj][Pp][Ee][Gg]
    do …
   ```
4. The `[…]` trick is a good one to know, but there a better way. 
   If I told you that there was a shell option called `nocaseglob`,
   could you guess what it does?

   ```
    shopt -s nullglob nocaseglob
    for file in *.jpg *.jpeg
    do …
   ```

   so now `*.jpg` means

   - (something), followed by
   - `.` (a period), followed by
   - "jpg", in some combination of upper case and lower case

   and so the above command
   will match `*.jpg`, `*.JPG`, `*.Jpg`, `*.jpeg`, `*.jPeG`, etc.
5. Another way is to use the `extglob` shell option
   to enable extended pattern matching operators. 
   You'll still want `nullglob` and `nocaseglob`. 
   The extended pattern matching operators all look like

   ```
   (some_special_character)  (  pattern-list  )
   ```

   where spaces are added for clarity,
   and *`pattern-list`* is a list of *`pattern`s*
   separated by `|` character(s). 
   The one that looks most interesting for your purposes is

   ```
   @(pattern-list)
   ```

   which means match one of the listed patterns. 
   So now the script becomes

   ```
    shopt -s nullglob nocaseglob extglob
    for file in *.@(jpg|jpeg)
    do …
   ```

   This may look like a little more typing,
   but the tradeoff shifts as the number of extensions grows.  Consider,

   ```
    for file in *.@(jpg|jpeg|jfif|exif|tif|tiff|gif|bmp|png|svg)
   ```

   is a bit shorter than

   ```
    for file in *.jpg *.jpeg *.jfif *.exif *.tif *.tiff *.gif *.bmp *.png *.svg
   ```
6. Where did you learn to do `$(echo …)`? 
   Sure, `$(some_command(s) …)` can certainly be useful,
   and maybe even `$(echo …)` sometimes, but you're overusing it. 
   It's perfectly good to say

   ```
    outputFile="image$i"
   ```

   and you probably don't even need the quotes
   (*in the assignment statement*).
7. OK, you can be excused *just this once*,
   since you know that the value of `outputFile` is benign,
   since you set it from a constant string of non-blank,
   non-special characters (`image`) plus a variable
   which you set to a constant string of non-blank, non-special characters (`1`)
   and did only trivial arithmetic operations on it. 
   But, as a general rule, you should *always* quote all reference
   to shell variables, unless you have a very good reason not to
   and you're sure you know what you're doing. 
   So your `convert` command, ideally, should be

   ```
    convert "$file" -resize 50x50 "$outputFile"
   ```

   (with quotes around `$outputFile`.)

Answer (score -1):

You would want to replace this part:

```
for file in *.jpg; do
```

By this:

```
for file in $(ls *.jpg *.JPG); do
```

Comment: using `ls` in a for loop like this is not recommended. See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)